# How to refresh a page with out refreshing another page

Tags: php

I have one page `named abcdxyz.php`, in this page I included two pages that is `abc.php` and `xyz.php`.I want ot refresh `xyz.php` without refreshing `abc.php`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply..Is there any other option

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side language so when you include stuff in your page it is treated like it is the part of the page(when rendered). To do what you intend to do i recommend using ajax.